# Contact form 7 sending to wrong email (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, forms, contacts, contact-form-7

I have changed all the email addresses to send where I want them to go in the fields, however upon sending an email through the form on the site I still receive emails to the unwanted test address I entered when beginning the site development.

Is there some sort of setting that all forms send to a default email?

How do I go about only making the form send to the email in the field?

I am using the paeon theme if that makes any difference?

Comment: you can just try to change your email id in `to` section

Comment: Go to `plugins-> contact form ->settings-> mail ->to` there you can give our custom email id

Comment: I have changed the email address here but still goes to the one I used for testing, there is no reason for it to send to the previous email but still does...it also sends to the new address, but I only want to receive emails for one

Comment: Do you have any type of accelerator or cache installed? Like APC, xCache?

Comment: I had this issue and it was due to plugin that leverages our gmail, and it automatically uses the gmail account name as the to:, with the contact form 7 to: field being ignored.  So check your mail plug ins.